Android per app language activity recreation animation
I have implemented per app language in my current Android application and change language using setApplicationLocales(). This causes the activity to completely restart giving a black blank screen while the recreation occurs.
Is there an approach I can take to refactor and improve this user experience? As this current implementation gives a very poor visual result. Is there a method to allow the app to fade out then back in

You can make the activity handle the locale configuration changes by itself by adding the following inside the activity declaration in AndroidManifest.xml.
android:configChanges="locale"

Adding this will tell the system not to recreate the activity for locale changes.
Then override onConfigurationChanged inside the activity (or fragment) where you can call Context.getString() to get the updated string value that you can pass to the views/screens.
